# How can I add macOS "Tags" to files programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, metadata, command-line-tool

Since Mavericks, OS X has had the ability to tag & colour files in Finder.

[image: finder tags]

Is there any way to add tags to files through Cocoa APIs or via a shell command?

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009101/using-multiple-keywords-in-xattr-via-kmditemusertags-or-kmditemomusertags). Which kind of tags are you talking about? I will give an answer for label color below, but the keywords and spotlight tags are a bit different.

Comment: @beroe I had originally become curious about this ability because I thought it would be nice to add a build step to my xCode build phases that would tag the build dir so it would be easily searchable in finder.  I see your accepted answer in the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009101/using-multiple-keywords-in-xattr-via-kmditemusertags-or-kmditemomusertags) but I have no experience with python can you provide a script that would run on a file as you did with colouring?

Comment: OK, I added a skeleton script that lets you tag folders or files with a word...

Comment: This answer of mine shows how to clear Tags and Label with AppleScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77788562/43615

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry for adding another answer, but the one related to setting Label colors was pretty long already. Here is an excerpt from a python script that I use to set the User Tags. It seems to work to make things searchable, but not sure if the tags will show up correctly. Usage is basically:

```
tagfile.py "Tag Name" FileOrFolderName
```

Code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" Write tags to file
Usage:
    tagfile.py "TagName" FileName1 FileName2 

    You can use wildcards for the file name. Use quotes if spaces in tags.
    To check if it worked, use xattr -l FileName

"""

import sys
import subprocess

def writexattrs(F,TagList):
    """ writexattrs(F,TagList):
    writes the list of tags to three xattr fields on a file-by file basis:
    "kMDItemFinderComment","_kMDItemUserTags","kMDItemOMUserTags
    Uses subprocess instead of xattr module. Slower but no dependencies"""

    Result = ""

    plistFront = '<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><array>'
    plistEnd = '</array></plist>'
    plistTagString = ''
    for Tag in TagList:
        plistTagString = plistTagString + '<string>{}</string>'.format(Tag.replace("'","-"))
    TagText = plistFront + plistTagString + plistEnd

    OptionalTag = "com.apple.metadata:"
    XattrList = ["kMDItemFinderComment","_kMDItemUserTags","kMDItemOMUserTags"]
    for Field in XattrList:    
        XattrCommand = 'xattr -w {0} \'{1}\' "{2}"'.format(OptionalTag + Field,TagText.encode("utf8"),F)
        if DEBUG:
            sys.stderr.write("XATTR: {}\n".format(XattrCommand))
        ProcString = subprocess.check_output(XattrCommand, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True) 
        Result += ProcString
    return Result

DEBUG = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print __doc__
    else:
        TagList = [ sys.argv[1] ]
        # print TagList
        # Or you can hardwire your tags here
        # TagList = ['Orange','Green']
        FileList = sys.argv[2:]

        for FileName in FileList:
            writexattrs(FileName, TagList)
```

Comment: Cool thanks, just tested this, it seems to work fine and file is searchable from finder via the tag.

Comment: +1 Works well, neverthless is very slow (more than 1 second).

Comment: @iacopo - If you are in a hurry, it might be faster to use the native Python library -- I just didn't want to have any dependencies. You can speed it up quite a bit by removing two of the tags and just do it on `_kMDItemUserTags` instead of all three. It is also possible to run the `xattr` command on a whole folder at a time recursively. Pretty much the same script but use `xattr -rw` and give it a folder name instead. I think for general purposes a file-by-file basis is more flexible, but clearly slower.

Comment: I changed line 48 of your script to `TagList = sys.argv[1].split(';')` so that more than one tag can be added if separated by `;`s

Comment: Pro Tip: place `tagfile.py` into `~/bin`, run `chmod +x ~/bin/tagfile.py` and run from other folders with `tagfile.py "SomeTag" ./some/Folder/orFile.txt`

Comment: `print __doc__` SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean `print(__doc__)`?

Comment: @FFish This was written 9 years ago in python2.7. :^)   I suppose it would be easy to update to be py3.x compatible, but I'm not sure if these same strategies still work with OSX 13.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, 9 years ago, time flies by  I just implemented with success https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/

Comment: That is great. Probably worth posting as an answer. I'd love to see your implementation.

Answer (score 15):

Check out tag, "a command line tool to manipulate tags on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks files, and to query for files with those tags". [The GitHub repository has installation instructions](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) (there are Homebrew and MacPorts packages).

Answer (score 6):

I add this answer, because OP asked for a shell script and tagged it *bash*. I wrote this Automator service, which tags the selected file with the tags of another file. I have added comments to outline the use of bash's interaction with the tags and colours using bash script.

#### Basics

In scripts both OpenMeta and Mavericks tags can be accessed with the command **xattr**. Using it without modifiers, `$ xattr [file]`, gives a list of set attributes. `$ xattr -h` gives a nice guide to usage.

Mavericks' tags are in com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags, while OpenMeta tags can be in a variety of attributes. Amongst others `com.apple.metadata:kOMUserTags`, `org.openmetainfo:kMDItemOMUserTags` and `org.openmetainfo:kOMUserTags`.

Mavericks handles colours and tags in different attributes, by placing tags in _kMDItemUserTags and colours in FinderInfo for every file. This is a bizarre choice, and it is one of the reasons Finder struggles under the pressure of tagging. If you have 800 files tagged *kapow*, each in a different folder, and you subsequently choose the colour blue for *kapow*, Finder has to find and alter attributes for every single file.

You can play around with the oddity by removing the com.apple.FinderInfo attribute from a tagged and coloured file: `$ xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo [file]`. The colour will disappear in Finder listings, but the tag (and its colour) remains associated with the file.

#### Bash script to import tags from another file

In the script, the selected file(s) in Finder is/are saved to the variable **$tagless**, and the chosen supplier of tags is **$tagfull**.

```
TAGFULID=${#@}
TAGFUL=${!TAGFULID}

## Use xattr to read all existing tags:
ATTRS=$(xattr "$TAGFUL")

for f in "$@" ## For every selected file in Finder, do:
do
    if("$TAGFUL"="$f") ## Is the supplier of tags is amongst the selected files?
    then
        break
    fi

    if [[ "$ATTRS" == *kMDItemUserTags* ]] ## Are there tags?
        then
        ## Load tags:
        TAGS=$(xattr -px com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags "$TAGFUL")
        ## Write tags:
        xattr -wx com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags "$TAGS" "$f"
    fi
    if [[ "$ATTRS" == *FinderInfo* ]] ## Are there colours?
    then
        ## Load colour:
        FINDERINFO=$(xattr -px com.apple.FinderInfo "$TAGFUL")
        ## Write colour:
        xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "$FINDERINFO" "$f"
    fi
done
```

[image: The Automator service]

Answer (score 5):

You could give [this](https://gist.github.com/Zettt/5880737) a shot:

```
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags '<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><array><string>Orange</string><string>Red</string></array></plist>' $currentFile
```

You'll want to replace $currentFile with the file you'd like to add tags to, and change

```
<string>Orange</string><string>Red</string>
```

to a list of whatever tags you want to add.

Comment: Note that editing the existing tag list this way will be tricky, since it's normally stored in binary plist form, not XML. Also, to do it right you really should also set the FinderInfo if there are any color tags in the list...

Comment: It seems you can use "[mdls](http://krypted.com/tag/xattr/) -name kMDItemUserTags $currentFile" to list even tags written in binary format in a more readable manner.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson how would you set the FinderInfo in the above example and why is that important?

Comment: @nacross: I don't have a better answer, I'm just pointing out that it's hard to do right.

Comment: Did what I needed in el capitan, as part of an automator script, for quickly tagging photos I like.

Answer (score 4):

In Apple's [What's New in OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_9.html) it states that `NSURL` handles tags, and the [Common File System Resource_Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Common_File_System_Resource_Keys) gives the required key as `NSURLTagNamesKey` and states its value is just an array of strings.

Comment: Adding new tags is as simple as setting the NSURLTagNamesKey resource value on a URL, specifying an array that contains a string (tag name) that doesn't already exist. It will show up in Finder immediately.

Answer (score 3):

This does not cover tags, but for changing label colors, one way to do it is through a command like this:

```
xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo \
0000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 myfile.txt
```

The `04` buried in the middle is setting the file color.

Here is a python script which wraps that command lets you set the tag color on a file or series of files:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def colorizeFile(ColorName,FileName):
    ReverseTable = {
         "clear"  :  "01",
         "gray"   :  "03",
         "green"  :  "04",
         "purple" :  "06",
         "blue"   :  "09",
         "yellow" :  "0A",
         "red"    :  "0C",
         "orange" :  "0E",
         "c"      :  "01",
         "a"      :  "03",
         "g"      :  "04",
         "p"      :  "06",
         "b"      :  "09",
         "y"      :  "0A",
         "r"      :  "0C",
         "o"      :  "0E",
    }

    HexString = 18*"0" + ReverseTable.get(ColorName) + 44*"0"
    Xcommand = 'xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo {0} {1}'.format(HexString,FileName)
    ProcString = subprocess.check_call(Xcommand, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)<3:
        sys.stderr.write(__doc__.format(sys.argv[0]))
    else:
        Cname = sys.argv[1]
        Flist = sys.argv[2:]
        for File in Flist:
            colorizeFile(Cname.lower(),File)
        sys.stderr.write("## Colorized {0} file(s) as {1}\n".format(len(Flist),Cname))
```

Usage is:

```
  labelcolor.py [color] *.jpg
```

where [color] is a name or abbreviation as defined below:

```
    clear (c), grAy (a), green (g), purple (p), 
    blue (b), yellow (y), red (r), orange (o)
```

Comment: thanks I tried out your script and it seems to work great for setting colours.  Unfortunately when I asked the question I made the faulty assumption that the method for setting tags and colours would be handled in the same manor.  I am mainly interested in setting a textual tag. +1 though for a useful and partial answer.

Comment: For some reason setting tags doesn't work so well. I am using the method in the linked answer to put keywords that spotlight can search on. I think for more than that, I would recommend using AppleScript called from the command line with `osascript`.

Comment: This might also check out [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106109/any-way-to-set-add-tags-on-a-file-with-applescript-under-mavericks).

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenMeta](http://code.google.com/p/openmeta/) framework is a third-party standard for adding metadata to OS X files using extended attributes. It is used by a number of third-party applications.

Or you can use the [XATTR](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) command to manipulate the extended attributes via command line.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with the Tags feature in Mavericks

Comment: Have you seen Sperr's answer on this post?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19720455/393564

Comment: I did not see the xattr part. Interesting. Surely there must be a better API than that. Presumably it'd be buried in multiple places and might be outside of sandbox land.

Comment: While the openmeta framework does provide tagging metadata, it is not a part of apple's proprietary tagging mechanism.

Comment: In fact Apple copied OpenMeta for its tagging system, only changing the xattr name. OpenMeta in its last for thus just sets Apple tags using Apples official API. There are some 'gotchas' that OpenMeta covers like case preserve/case insentivie tags, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Starting with Mavericks, it is possible to get and set color tags in Cocoa, using `NSURL`.**

`NSURL` has a slew of properties that can be set or read, through the respective `setResourceValue:forKey:error:` and `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` methods.

Using the `NSURLLabelNumberKey` key, you can set the color tags, as follows:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/[username]/Documents/[some_file]"];
NSError *resourceError;
if (![fileURL setResourceValue:@(2) forKey:NSURLLabelNumberKey error:&resourceError]) {
    NSLog(@"Error while setting file resource: %@", [resourceError localizedDescription]);
}
```

If this is executed on a file that only has one color, then it clears the current color, and sets the specified color. However, if multiple colors are already set on the file, then it does not clear the existing colors before setting the specified color.

Here is the value-color mapping (on El Capitan):

- @(0): None
- @(1): Grey
- @(2): Green
- @(3): Purple
- @(4): Blue
- @(5): Yellow
- @(6): Red
- @(7): Orange

I have not been able to set a tag using `NSURLLabelColorKey`. Here is my experience on El Capitan, with the keys related to 'tags' (Colors):

- `NSURLLabelNumberKey`: can be read/set successfully, with numbers 0-7. Any other number will return an error. If there are multiple tags set, then this will return the index of the first color that is set, as it searches numerically through the indexes 1 through 7. Although you can clear a color in Finder by clicking on the color, programmatically setting a color that is already set does not clear that color.
- `NSURLLabelColorKey`: returns nil, even when a color tag is set for a file. Setting a value with this key has no effect.
- `NSURLTagNamesKey`: returns an array of the color names for the tags that are set.

Comment: How do I set arbitrary tags, like "Financial", using this API?

Comment: What this answer describes is not about setting Tags but the single Label for a file. Labels are an older concept, which is somewhat translated into Tags, but is not foolproof. Accessing the real Tags works thru `NSURLTagNamesKey`, as explained in CRD's answer.

Answer (score 0):

### In Ask Different

With multiple answers, one of which is [accepted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110709/8546):

- [Possible to tag a folder via terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110662/8546) (2013-11-15)

---

Here in Stack Overflow the question arose slightly earlier (2013-11-01) so I'll add my answer here.

### openmeta

Open source at https://code.google.com/p/openmeta/source/browse/trunk/trunk/openmeta

The `openmeta` command appears to take a dual attribute approach, working with both:

- `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags`
- `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags`

#### Example usage

```
sh-3.2$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F1096
sh-3.2$ uname -a
Darwin gpes3e-gjp4.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
sh-3.2$ date
Sun 26 Jul 2015 08:00:23 BST
sh-3.2$ rm ~/Desktop/test.txt 
sh-3.2$ touch ~/Desktop/test.txt 
sh-3.2$ xattr -l ~/Desktop/test.txt 
sh-3.2$ ./openmeta
openmeta version 0.1 by Tom Andersen code.google.com/p/openmeta/ 

Usage: openmeta [options] -p PATH[s] 

Note that commas are to be used nowhere - tag lists use quotes for two word tags in output

example (list tags and ratings):  openmeta -p PATH
example (list tags and ratings multiple):  openmeta -p PATH PATH
example (list tags): openmeta -t -p PATH[s]
example (add tags): openmeta -a foo bar -p PATH[s]
example (add tags with spaces): openmeta -a "three word tag" "foo bar" -p PATH[s]
example (set tags):  openmeta -s foo bar -p PATH[s]
example (clear all tags):  openmeta -s -p PATH[s]
example (set managed):  openmeta -m Y -p PATH[s]
example (set rating 0 - 5 stars):  openmeta -r 3.5 -p PATH[s]
example (print rating):  openmeta -r -p PATH[s]
example (clear rating):  openmeta -r 0.0 -p PATH[s]
example (lousy rating):  openmeta -r 0.1 -p PATH[s]
sh-3.2$ ./openmeta -a kerfuffle -p ~/Desktop/test.txt 
kerfuffle /Users/gjp22/Desktop/test.txt
sh-3.2$ ./openmeta -p ~/Desktop/test.txt 
/Users/gjp22/Desktop/test.txt
tags: kerfuffle
rating: none found

sh-3.2$ xattr -l ~/Desktop/test.txt 
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTagTime:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 33 41 BB 64 BD 3C D4 95  |bplist003A.d.<..|
00000010  F2 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 11                                            |..|
00000032
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 59 6B 65 72 66 75  |bplist00..Ykerfu|
00000010  66 66 6C 65 08 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00  |ffle............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 14                                |......|
00000036
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 5B 6B 65 72 66 75  |bplist00..[kerfu|
00000010  66 66 6C 65 0A 30 08 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01  |ffle.0..........|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16                          |........|
00000038
kOM109SyncDone:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 09 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  |bplist00........|
00000010  01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09                    |..........|
0000002a
sh-3.2$
```

#### Limitations of other utilities

Apple Finder, for example.

After using Finder to remove the *kerfuffle* tag, *kerfuffle* remains as an OpenMeta tag:

```
sh-3.2$ date ; xattr -l ~/Desktop/test.txt 
Sun 26 Jul 2015 08:02:13 BST
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTagTime:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 33 41 BB 64 BD 3C D4 95  |bplist003A.d.<..|
00000010  F2 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 11                                            |..|
00000032
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 59 6B 65 72 66 75  |bplist00..Ykerfu|
00000010  66 66 6C 65 08 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00  |ffle............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 14                                |......|
00000036
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A0 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  |bplist00........|
00000010  01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09                    |..........|
0000002a
kOM109SyncDone:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 09 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  |bplist00........|
00000010  01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09                    |..........|
0000002a
sh-3.2$
```

#### Understanding those limitations

With attention to domains and naming conventions: [Developer thoughts on adopting OpenMeta – Ironic Software](http://web.archive.org/web/20150726073650/http://ironicsoftware.com/vanillaforums/discussion/755/developer-thoughts-on-adopting-openmeta) (2009-03, and now in the Internet Archive Wayback Machine) reminds us that `com.apple.metadata` was for use by Apple when OpenMeta (a project **not** in the `apple.com` domain) began the Apple-oriented `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags` approach.

So I should not expect Apple software to gain or maintain compatibility with both approaches to tagging.

---

### Edge cases

In some cases it may be desirable to remove **Apple**-oriented `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` tags *without removing* **OpenMeta**-oriented `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags` tags.

However, doing so – programmatically – is probably beyond the scope of the question asked by @nacross.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented OSXMETADATA in Python to copy OSX finder tags

https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/