# Removing Finder Tags (and Label) with Applescript

Tags: applescript, osx-mavericks

I am trying to recursively remove all the tags (one of the new features of OS X 10.9) from all the contents of a folder. As there are many files in the folder (and folders which contain further files), I wanted to try and use Applescript to make the process easier. I have looked online and have not found anything useful.

Also, I cannot find anything in the Finder or Standard Additions dictionary that will help me.

Possibly something that works like this:

```
set folder to "folder_path"
set files to (all files of folder)
for each file:
    check for tag (optional)
    remove all tags from file
```

PS. The above code is supposed to be a guide to what the script does, not the exact code to make it work.

Comment: For getting and adding Tags, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77792397/43615

Answer (score 3):

This will recursively remove all tags from the files of a folder:

```
set targetFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Remove all tags from this folder..." default location path to desktop)

do shell script "xattr -rd com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags " & quoted form of targetFolder
```

Comment: When using `mdls ~/Desktop/Folder/test.rtf`, I can see the `kMDItemUserTags` attribute, but when I try to use `xattr -rd com.apple.metadata...`, an error appears saying `No such xattr: com.apple.metatdata:_kMDItemUserTags`

Comment: Can you post an example file?

Comment: To see whether a file has the tags attached, use the `xattr` command, not `mdls`. If it lists `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` amoung the output, it has Tags that you can remove with `xattr -d com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags`

Comment: The problem is that by removing the xattr it still leaves the old-style "Label" set. That needs to be cleared separately (see Simon White's answer for that).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you are having is that your files do not actually have tags on them — they probably just have labels.

Although the new tag system in Mavericks is built to incorporate the old label system by showing labels as tags, files that were labeled yellow in versions of Mac OS X prior to Mavericks may not actually have proper tags on them. They just have old school labels, which Mavericks is showing as tags. If the tags on your files are things like yellow and blue, those are likely just labels. And that may be why you are seeing an error when trying to remove them with xattr.

So if your files only have labels, the way to remove the labels is the same as if you were still running Mountain Lion. You ask Finder to set the label index of the files to 0.

This AppleScript asks you to choose a folder, then it loops through all the files in that folder, and if a file has a label on it, the label is removed.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose a folder to remove labels from the files within:")
    set theFiles to every file of theFolder
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        if the label index of theFile is not equal to 0 then
            set the label index of theFile to 0
        end if
    end repeat
    open theFolder
end tell
```

To be clear: the above AppleScript only removes the 7 standard tag/label colors that have existed since before Mac OS X. If you manually tagged files in Mavericks by opening up a Get Info window and typing in a project name or something like that as a tag, then that tag will have to be removed via shell scripting as described in adayzdone’s response above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution that works for clearing both the Tags and the Label. Basically a combination of the two other answers.

If you save this AppleScript as an application, you can drop files and folders onto it and their Tags + Label will be cleared.

```
-- A script for removing all Tags and the Label from files & folders
--
-- The following handler gets executed when files are dropped onto
-- this script (when saved as an application)
--
-- Author: Thomas Tempelmann

use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

on open of theFiles
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        set posixPath to (POSIX path of aFile)
        if true then
            -- remove Tags with ASObjC code
            set aURL to (current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:posixPath) -- make URL
            (aURL's setResourceValue:{} forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value))
        else
            -- remove Tags with a shell command
            try
                set qpath to quoted form of posixPath
                do shell script "/usr/bin/xattr -d com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags " & qpath
            end try
        end if
        -- remove the Label through the Finder's Applescript support
        tell application "Finder"
            if the label index of aFile is not equal to 0 then
                set the label index of aFile to 0
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end open

-- let user choose a file if this script is run without providing input files
open (choose file)
```

You can also turn this into a **Service** so that you can right-click on files in Finder to remove their Tags: Open **Automator.app**, create a new Service, add an AppleScript action, set the "Service receives selected" popup to "files or folders" and paste the code into it, changing the first line to `on run {theFiles, parameters}`. Then save it, e.g. named "Remove Tags and Label". Next time you right-click on a file in Finder, look at the bottom of the contextual menu for Services, in which you'll find this command then.