# Changing Finder Labels with AppleScript

Tags: tags, applescript, finder

I want to assign specific tags to selected files in Finder (OS X 10.9.4), using AppleScript and [tag](http://brewformulas.org/Tag), but I'm having problems passing the file path to tag.

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        repeat with currentFile in items of (get selection)
            if label index of currentFile is 0 then
                do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/tag -a 'foo' " & currentFile)
            else
                set label index of currentFile to 0
            end if
        end repeat
    on error e
        return e
    end try
end tell
```

If I have `/Users/fort/bar.txt` selected in Finder, I get the following error:

```
"tag: The file “/Users/fort/bar.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
```

However, the following code does change the tag of the specified file to `foo`:

`set myFile to "/Users/fort/bar.txt" 
do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/tag -a 'foo' " & myFile)`

Any idea why `currentFile` isn't being passed to [tag](http://brewformulas.org/Tag) in a way it can parse? Thanks.

fort

Comment: is that the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: I added quotes by mistake, and the name of my Mac HD (which is MBA) should be prepended to the path. And, obviously, the filename is made up. So, the exact error would look like this: `tag: The file “MBA/Users/fort/bar.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.`

Comment: You're not dealing with Tags but with Labels here. Tags are a newer concept, being a set of names, which _can_ have a color each. Labels are an older concept where you can assign only a single pre-set label out of 7 fixed choices. AppleScript (Finder) doesn't appear to provide access to the Tags so far.

Comment: To work with actual Tags, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77792397/43615

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a path problem, you must convert Finder item to a string, and convert the HFS path to posix path

Try this

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with currentFile in (get selection)
        tell currentFile
            if label index is 0 then
                my tagCmd(it as text) -- convert Finder item e.g. file "bar.txt" of folder "fort" of.... -->  "MBA:Users:fort:bar.txt” (path with colon)
            else
                set label index to 0
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

on tagCmd(f)
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/tag -a 'foo' " & quoted form of POSIX path of f -- posix path convert path with colon to use in shell
end tagCmd
```

Comment: That worked, thanks @jackjr300! The only thing which isn't working is the tag toggle, but that doesn't matter, since I've made another script that removes all tags.

Comment: can you post the script that removes all tags?

Comment: See here for removing actual Tags from files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77788562/43615