# Access Finder Tags with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I'm not looking for too much help today just a simple command, I already have the bare bones to what I need.
So Really simple question I am writing an  AppleScript that sets my wallpaper based on the Finder Image Tag.
Just want to know how do you access Finders Tags in Applescript ... I only can find Finder Labels ??? I have the logic worked out, I just need the method or function or command responsible for obtaining Finder Tags as highlighted in the image below.

Please and thank-you :)

[image: Apple Finder Tags]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new tags aren’t directly supported in AppleScript yet. You have to read them and set them via shell scripting, which you can access from AppleScript with the “do shell script” command. The shell command that you want is “xattr” which enables you to manipulate file metadata on an OS X system. You can type “man xattr” into the Terminal application to get the xattr manual.

There is also a 3rd party tool called “tag” which may be helpful, because xattr is fairly complicated:

Tag — A command line tool to manipulate tags on Mavericks files, and to query for files with those tags.

http://brewformulas.org/Tag

Comment: Just wanted to share a cool tip for OSX manpages... just type the command you are about to use and want to see the manpage for, then right-click with the mouse and you get a yellow pop-up window with the manpage that you can scroll up and down and refer to while you are concocting your command without needing a second Terminal window :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answers can be found on other platforms, e.g. MacScripter.

I'm posting a solution here that I found there, with example use:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

-- The following functions work in macOS 10.9 and later
--
-- Origin of code: https://www.macscripter.net/t/adding-finder-tags/70025/2
-- Author: Shane Stanley

on returnTagsFor:posixPath -- get the tags
    set aURL to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:posixPath -- make URL
    set {theResult, theTags} to aURL's getResourceValue:(reference) forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
    if theTags = missing value then return {} -- because when there are none, it returns missing value
    return theTags as list
end returnTagsFor:

on setTags:tagList forPath:posixPath -- set the tags, replacing any existing
    set aURL to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:posixPath -- make URL
    aURL's setResourceValue:tagList forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
end setTags:forPath:

on addTags:tagList forPath:posixPath -- add to existing tags
    set aURL to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:posixPath -- make URL
    -- get existing tags
    set {theResult, theTags} to aURL's getResourceValue:(reference) forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
    if theTags is not missing value then -- add new tags
        set tagList to (theTags as list) & tagList
        set tagList to (current application's NSOrderedSet's orderedSetWithArray:tagList)'s allObjects() -- delete any duplicates
    end if
    aURL's setResourceValue:tagList forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
end addTags:forPath:

-- How to use the above functions:

set theItem to (choose file)

set tags1 to my returnTagsFor:(POSIX path of theItem) -- retrieves Tags
my addTags:{"Tag 1", "Tag 2"} forPath:(POSIX path of theItem) -- adds Tags
set tags2 to my returnTagsFor:(POSIX path of theItem)

set previousDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
display dialog "Tags before change:" & return & tags1 & return & return & "after:" & return & tags2
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to previousDelimiters
```