# Get all filesystem tags

Tags: cocoa, tags, osx-mavericks, hfs+

Since OSX Mavericks supports file tags. Is there any API to access these programmatically? How can I get a list of all system tags? And manipulate them?

I tried already:

- NSFileManager class
- File System Programming Guide
- File Metadata Search Programming Guide

yet none of those mention the existance of tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all system tags in this path: 
`~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

But the default the plist file doesn't exist. You can make it appear by adding a new tag. By the way, do you find other way to get all system tags?

Comment: For a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41780350/2150405

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether this is what you are looking for:

see this thread for adding tags programmatically [How can I add OS X "tags" to files programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720376/osx-mavericks-add-tags-programmatically)

also if you look at the NSURL reources page http://goo.gl/fwHMWk  it says about getting names of tags attached to the resource, returned as an array of NSString values using the NSURLTagNamesKey.

Comment: Thanks! Although your answer is OK dealing with single resources, I am trying to find the way to access the tags without individual files. I want all filesystem tags and being able to perform actions like system wide renaming. I have an script that searches the whole filesystem, extract tags for each file, and reduce it removing duplicates. That is far too much work and I thought there is some more effective way

Answer (score 0):

You can read finder user defaults

```
defaults read com.apple.Finder FavoriteTagNames  

(
    "",
    Red,
    Orange,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Purple,
    Gray
)
```

Comment: Just like the command reads, those are just the "Favorite Tags"