# How do I retrieve all available Finder tags?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, finder

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all the available Finder tags.

I found `NSWorkspace().fileLabels`, which does return an array, but only an array of the tag colours, not the tags themselves:

```
print(NSWorkspace.shared().fileLabels) // prints ["None", "Gray", "Green", "Purple", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Orange"]
```

Which as you can see is not even all the default tags, it's missing **Home**, **Work** and **Important**, and obviously doesn't have any of the custom ones that I created. It looks like it's just the nice names that go with fileLabelColors.

I found NSMetadataQuery for actually searching for things, but how do I get a list of all the tags I have created in the Finder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSWorkspace.shared().fileLabels` only returns the system tags that were available when the user account was created (the default system tags).

There's unfortunately no API in macOS to retrieve the tags that you have created yourself in the Finder.

The solution is to parse the `~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist`:

```
func allTagLabels() -> [String] {
    // this doesn't work if the app is Sandboxed:
    // the users would have to point to the file themselves with NSOpenPanel
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSHomeDirectory())/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist")
    let keyPath = "values.FinderTagDict.value.FinderTags"
    if let d = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        if let plist = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: d, options: [], format: nil),
            let pdict = plist as? NSDictionary,
            let ftags = pdict.value(forKeyPath: keyPath) as? [[AnyHashable: Any]]
        {
            return ftags.flatMap { $0["n"] as? String }
        }
    }
    return []
}

let all = allTagLabels()
print(all)
```

This gets *all* Finder tags labels.

You can also select only the custom tags (ignore the system ones):

```
func customTagLabels() -> [String] {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSHomeDirectory())/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist")
    let keyPath = "values.FinderTagDict.value.FinderTags"
    if let d = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        if let plist = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: d, options: [], format: nil),
            let pdict = plist as? NSDictionary,
            let ftags = pdict.value(forKeyPath: keyPath) as? [[AnyHashable: Any]]
        {
            return ftags.flatMap { tag in
                if let n = tag["n"] as? String,
                    tag.values.count != 2
                {
                    return n
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. A followup question though, since clearly I found no documentation on this, do you know where things like the com.apple.finder.plist are documented. Also, just as a FYI `allTagLabels` did return all tags, but `customTagLabels` didn't return all custom tags I had created. Going through the differences will actually probably be useful for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, as there's no public API anymore for this, there's no valid documentation anymore. You can print the contents of `pdict` to see all what's available in this plist file.

Comment: Do you know how get the color from custom labels ?

Comment: Unfortunately this `~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist` isn't accessible with Sandbox enabled.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it's mentioned in a comment in the code (first example). The solution for a sandboxed app is to have the user select the file themselves with NSOpenPanel, then you can get the file url.

Comment: @ayaio Thanks. That‘s but very user friendly, but that’s a general problem.

Comment: On Monterey (12.0), this file is no longer present in that directory. It has moved to ~/Library/Preferences, BUT the contents are different, AND, they no longer contain all the necessary information. Now, only the tag names are present, but not the mapping to colors. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: @NikBhatt Check out my answer for Monterey.

Answer (score 7):

After some digging with "Hopper Disassembler" and my own "Find Any File" (for text search in files), I figured out where the Tags are now stored since Monterey:

The file `~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.kvs/com.apple.KeyValueService-Production.sqlite` contains the same plist data that was previously stored in `~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist`.

But it's now hidden inside a database record:

If you look into the ZSYSDMANAGEDKEYVALUE table, you'll find a single entry with ZKEY="FinderTagDict". The ZPLISTDATAVLUE contains a bplist record, which contains the pblist (binary plist) structure, from which you can then extract the tags.

Comment: Here's a working script for the solution found by Thomas Tempelmann (credit also goes to James Walker):

sqlite3 ~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.kvs/com.apple.KeyValueService-Production.sqlite "SELECT writefile('path/to//tags.plist', ZPLISTDATAVALUE) FROM ZSYDMANAGEDKEYVALUE WHERE ZKEY = 'FinderTagDict';"

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt to solve the question for Monterey (and it also works in earlier systems such as High Sierra).

It might  also work in sandboxed apps, as long as you're allowed to use `System Events` in scripts (I know from own experience that it's generally not allowed for apps in the Mac App Store, though). At worst, you'd have to support user-installed scripts and then instruct your users to install the script below manually *(and I also suggest to avoid bothering the user with this operation within the first hour since the first launch of the app, or the reviewer may get triggered and reject your app regardless)*.

The best I could come up with is to use AppleScript to read the tag names from the Finder's Preferences window, see below.

But it's lame because it has to actually open the Finders's Prefs window briefly for this. Still, better than nothing.

```applescript
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

set prefsWinWasOpen to false

tell application "Finder"
    set prefs to Finder preferences
    set prefsWin to window of prefs
    tell prefsWin
        try
            get id
            set prefsWinWasOpen to true
        on error
            set prefsWinWasOpen to false
            open
        end try
        set current panel to Label Preferences panel
    end tell
end tell

set rowNames to {}

tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of (first application process whose name is "Finder")
        set uiElems to entire contents
        repeat with uiElem in uiElems
            if class of uiElem is table then
                set theTable to uiElem
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        set itsRows to rows of theTable
        repeat with oneRow in itsRows
            set end of rowNames to name of first UI element of oneRow
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

if not prefsWinWasOpen then
    tell application "Finder"
        close prefsWin
    end tell
end if

return rowNames
```