# set finder tags from swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I can get finder tags in swift using the following code:

```
if let tagArray = try url.resourceValues(forKeys:[.tagNamesKey]).tagNames {
    ...
}
```

But setting it will result in an error:

```
var values = URLResourceValues()
values.tagNames = finderTags
```

Gives the error:

```
Compile Swift Module 'tagsync' (1 sources)
main.swift:104:20: error: cannot assign to property: 'tagNames' is a get-only property
                    values.tagNames = finderTags
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

How can one write the tags from swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know of to do it is to write the `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` extended attribute, which you can do using the `setxattr` API.

Comment: I found this example helpful to write the tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example

Answer (score 2):

You can write Finder tags easily by using NSURL (not URL):

```
let myPath = "any POSIX path; spaces ok"  
var myFinderTags = ["a", "b", "c"]  
try NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myPath).setResourceValues([.tagNamesKey: myFinderTags])
```

Comment: This will set the file url tags not the Finder's tags

Comment: @LeoDabus What’s the difference? This seems to set the `kMDItemUserTags` just fine.

Comment: @user137369 You can create your own tags with Finder. But you are probably right I think the finder stores it at the volume url. Btw related https://stackoverflow.com/q/41779969/2303865